# number format exception when printing data from database into jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets

im trying to print a list with model data, from `Customer class`, im using jpa and servlet to pass data to jsp. As soon as the Search servlet gets loaded ill get the exception `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "firstName"`

Heres my servlet method :

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


    CustomerDAO dao = new CustomerDAO();
    Customer customer = new Customer();     
    List<Customer> customers = dao.getAllCustomers();

    request.setAttribute("customer", customers);

    request.getRequestDispatcher("/Search.jsp").forward(request, response);


}
```

Jsp page :

```
<tbody>
<c:forEach var="entry" items="${customer }"> 
 <c:out value = "${entry}" />
<tr> 
<td>
<div id="">
${customer.firstName } 
</div>
</td>
<td>${customer.surname} </td>
<td> ${customer.code } </td>
<td> ${customer.customerType } </td>
<td><a id='' href='./Search?do=delete&code='>Delete</a></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

And stacktrace :

```
Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:335)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
servlet.Search.doGet(Search.java:33)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be 'entry' instead of 'customer'

```
<tbody>  
<c:forEach var="entry" items="${customer }">   
 <c:out value = "${entry}" />  
<tr>   
<td>  
<div id="">  
${entry.firstName }   
</div>  
</td>  
<td>${entry.surname} </td>  
<td> ${entry.code } </td>  
<td> ${entry.customerType } </td>  
<td><a id='' href='./Search?do=delete&code='>Delete</a></td>  
</tr>  
</c:forEach>  
</tbody>
```